# Add request header field to JMeter WebService(SOAP) Request

Tags: java, web-services, gzip, jmeter

It seems like the **WebService(SOAP) Request** of **JMeter** does not include headers in the request defined in a **HTTP Header Manager**.

I want to send **Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate** with every SOAP request of my JMeter test - is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: This still seems to be an issue with JMeter so your post helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround for me was to use the **SOAP/XML-RPC Request** Sampler instead of the the **WebService(SOAP) Request**. This one sends the configured request headers to the server.

After that I found out that the incoming compressed response was not decompressed so I filed a bug at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48542 and created a patch. The bug is fixed in the trunk and should be included in the current nightly build.